# Python Curses: Controlling Two Terminals with One Script (Linux)

Tags: python, curses, tty, terminal

I would like to make a single Python script to control curses in two seperate terminal windows.  Not curses windows within a single terminal, but two different instances of, say, urxvt in my X window manager.

Something like this:

```
class myprogam():

    controlterm1()
    controlterm2()

    def controlterm1():
        Create a new (could be current) urxvt terminal window.
        In the urxvt window setup curses with curses.initscr(), etc.
        racergame()

    def controlterm2():
        Create another urxvt terminal window.
        Setup curses.initscr, borders, size, etc. in window, leaving the old one alone.
        typewriter()  

    def racecargame():
        Racing game in curses

    def typwritter()
        Boring program for writing

myprogram()
```

I see that pseudo-terminal windows are given a name when I use the command "tty", and this gives me a reference to /dev/pts/somenumber, where the first terminal emulator is assigned a zero, then 1, 2, etc for new terminals.  Can I use this identifier as a basis to do this?

The script does NOT have to actually load a new instance of urxvt, as I am happy if it can just control one that is already open.

Answer (score 3):

In principle there is no problem with opening multiple devices and doing I/O to them from one script. HOWEVER, most curses software that I've seen assumes it does I/O to the one terminal associated with the program.  For example, initscr takes no parameters.  It looks at your environment variables to determine your terminal characteristics.

Given that, it might be easier to split your program into two, one running on each terminal, which communicate via message-passing.

Comment: It is definitely easy cutting the program into 2, which is what I did for the prototype.  

So, if initscr() outputs to the terminal it finds in environmental variables, can the environmental variables be changed on the fly, to dupe it into outputting elsewhere?

Comment: You could try, but I doubt it.  What's wrong with leaving it as two separate processes that each manage a display?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but if you initiated a new program, you'd be importing things redundantly, and it feels hacked together.  Am I missing something?  A way to call a new program while avoiding redundant module imports?

Answer (score 3):

The ncurses C API has the `newterm` function that can be used to initialize the screen.  According to the `newterm` man page:

> A program that outputs to more than one terminal should use the newterm routine for each terminal instead of initscr.

However, the python curses module does not implement newterm.

Comment: I encountered newterm, and considered trying out C to do it.  But I couldn't help but think there was something in python that could offer me a work around.  Admittedly I am having troubles finding such a workaround.  Would the pty module help at all?  
http://docs.python.org/library/pty.html

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?